# Ipython1.1 notebook font change not working via css file

Tags: css, fonts, jupyter-notebook

I have tried to change some setting especially the fonts in my ipython 1.1 notebook via creating a profile and editing the costum.css but it is not working in windows 7.

My custom.css file is in   Users/"user_name"/.ipyton/profile_default/static/css directory

and I have added these line to the file

```
<style>

div.cell.code_cell {  /* Areat containing both code and output */
font-family: Consolas, monospace;
}

</style>
```

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `<style>` tags in the custom.css file!
A nice example on styling the IPython notebook can be found [here](http://zulko.wordpress.com/2013/04/14/customize-your-ipython-notebook-with-css/)

Comment: I have tried that and the styles in the link but none is working unfortunatelly. There must be something wrong with the instalation maybe. It is WinPython-64bit-3.3.2.3

Comment: Have you tried with something less error prone like `font-size: 2.2em;` in the css file? Does your style works as expected if entered in a markdown cell (with <style>)?

Comment: Yes it works in markdown cell with <style> but only the font size works the font itself does not change

Comment: so it looks like your font is not recognized!

Comment: I agree but I have tried every font and no change Maybe something is overriding??

Comment: I did it I was using "" with the font name  but it has to be without ""